# Cambiar de repositorio remoto en un repositorio local con git

Tags: git, gitlab

Soy relativamente nuevo en esto de uso de git. La pregunta es:

si tengo un repositorio local, clonado desde un repositorio remoto en gitlab, y quiero dejar de utilizar esa cuenta de gitlab y usar otra, al intentar borrar en el repositorio local con:

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

y le añado el otro repositorio remoto con:

```
$ git remote add origin2  https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git
```

todo bien. Cabe señalar que ya cuento con el repositorio remoto creado en la otra cuenta que quiero usar. Pero cuando intento subir el repositorio local a ese repositorio remoto añadido o creado nuevo(ya intenté borar el origin, y también intenté dejándolo y añadir el origin2) me da el siguiente error al intentar hacer el push:

```
$ git push origin2
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git/' not found
```

al checar los repositorios remotos asociados al repositorio local me da la siguiente lista:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/usuario_original/repositorio_original.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/usuario_original/repositorio_original.git (push)
origin2 https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git (fetch)
origin2 https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git (push)
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal, qué falta hacer, o no es posible lo que quiero hacer(conservar el historial de cambios que ya he hecho en ese repositorio, pero dejar de usar esa cuenta de gitlab y usar otra del mismo gitlab) ?

Comment: Hasta donde se y he hecho yo solo con colocar `git remote add origin` y la url nueva me basta para cambiar el origen remoto, luego con `git push -u origin master`por ejemplo, subo cambios a este.

Comment: están bien los permisos en el repo 2 con el user que venis usando en el repo1? ya sea como member o agregando tu public key? si clonas repo2 en otro lado funciona?

Answer (score 13):

Malo:

```
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin2 https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git
```

Bueno:

```
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git
```

Muy Bueno:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git
```

Por archivos: Puedes entrar a la ruta ".git/config " y editar la url

Comment: explica por que es malo y porque es bueno por fvavor

Comment: En referencia al error, **[Malo]** no era necesario duplicar el origen,**[Bueno]** inclusive no es necesario eliminarlo para volverlo a crear, **[Muy Bueno]** basta con cambiar la ruta donde apunta el origen.

Answer (score 5):

Hola tambien me pasó lo mismo:

```
rm -rf .git // esto eliminará todo lo relacionado a tu repositorio git
git init  // inicilizas un nuevo repositorio git en tu proyecto
git remote add origin  https://gitlab.com/otro_usuario/otro_repositorio.git // agregas el nuevo repositorio donde subirás los cambios
```

Comment: Rápido y conciso. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El comando para cambiar el origen de un repositorio remoto existente en git es este:

```
git remote set-url origin <tu nueva url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas tratando de usar uno para local y otra rama para remote, al que quieres local no necesitas hacer push, push y pull son para repositorios remotos, una ves haces commit ya se hizo la acción puedes confirmarlo con :

$ git log